# How to render MVC Custom Helper through jQuery MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I want to pass jQuery object(List) to MVC4 custom HTML Helper.

My view something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var datafilterList = GetDataFilter('@Url.Action("GetJsonDataFilter")'); // this is external file ajax call and I am getting the data pulled from controller. all ok here.
    @Html.DataFilterFor(datafilterList) // how to pass datafilterList and call custom helper??
});
</script>
```

My Helper Class:

```
public static class DataFilter
{
    public static MvcHtmlString DataFilterFor(this HtmlHelper html, List<View_webpages_DataFilter> DataFilterList)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // TODO: Create the form and render html - I removed the unnecessary html code
        return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Please can any one tell me how do I pass the jquery object datafilterList to mvc custom helper?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant. Razor code (the helper) runs on the server when the view is created and before it is sent to the browser.  Javascript runs on the browser and as no concept of what a html helper is.

Even if theoretically this was possible, what you are doing is sending a page to the server, then oops!, I forgot some data so go back to the server and return it, and then oops again, what I really wanted was some html, so go back to the server and return it. Why all these round trips when you could have done it once when the page was being created.

Either:

1. Get what ever the data is returned by `GetDataFilter()` in the
   action method you are using to generate this view and render the
   html (either directly in he view or call an child action to include
   a partial view); or if you prefer AJAX
2. Have the `GetJsonDataFilter()` function return the html you want (or call
   another method that returns the html) and then in its success
   function, add the html to the DOM

Comment: Actually I am not sending a page to a server and it is not the case that I forgot to pull some data. I designed in that way. I am just calling MVC controller through AJAX. And I am using multiple calls because some data will be pulled at a specific time. Also I am using jTable so I don't want to change the internal jTable libraries. So I have to have multiple AJAX calls. And I think this is absolutely fine. Back to the question: isn't there a way to decode the jQuery object and pass it to MVC custom helper?

Comment: No, because a html helper runs on the server. If you cant use option 1 because you need to call `GetDataFilter()` at a particular point in time, then you need to use option 2

Comment: ok i got the idea. is it ok if I fetch the data in the html helper class? : For example: 

@Html.DataFilterFor("1234") - this i write in the view

inline `
public static class DataFilter
{
    public static MvcHtmlString DataFilterFor(this HtmlHelper html, int menuid)
    {
        // Get the data from database for menuid and return HTML
    }
}
`

Comment: I would do this. After you have called `var datafilterList = ..`, then something like `$.get('/SomeController/SomeAction', { id: datafilterList }, function(data) { $('SomeElement').html(data); });` where `public ActionResult SomeAction(int id) {..` returns the html. You don't necessarily it to be a html helper (i.e. your could remove the `this HtmlHelper html` parameter) unless your also using it for other views. Alternatively, use the helper in a partial view and then `return PartialView("SomeView, model");`. I can update the answer with an example if you want.

Comment: I was thinking of using HtmlHelper casting like this but it won't work. 
@Html.DataFilterFor((List<View_webpages_DataFilter>)Html.Raw(Json.Decode(filterModel)))

I agree with you. I shouldn't be so stubborn about HtmlHelper and I must remove in my case. 

It is also nice if I use ajax get and render html using $('SomeElement').html(data); but then I will have to write this on each and every view.

Better I will go for partialview. Thanks

Comment: Well you can always combine the `$.get()` code snippet with the `GetDataFilter()` function to avoid repeating code - just pass in an additional parameter for the ID of the html element where you want to render the contents of the result